# How to add a header image for all pages in WordPress except the front page?

Tags: wordpress

I am running

WordPress 5.2.4 running Astrid theme.

I have added a header image for the front page.  It is displaying fine. Now, I would like to add one image for rest of the pages.  When I go to

Appearance > Header Area > Header Type

I see there is an option to set header type to images for rest of the pages.

[image]

But I do not see an option anywhere to specify an image.

Is there a way I can set an image for rest of the pages?

Answer (score 0):

you have to add filter action in to your active theme function.php file where you can specify header images for home and other pages. Please check below code it's working fine for me.

```
function change_header_img($url_for_image) {
    if (is_front_page() && is_home()){ 
        $url_for_image = "http://localhost/.../bg-section.jpg"; //home or front page header image link
    }else {
        $url_for_image = "http://localhost/.../1920x400.png"; //other pages header image link
    }
    return $url_for_image;
}
add_filter('theme_mod_header_image', 'change_header_img');
```

Comment: Let me try it out.  Thanks